# Pre-configured OpenVPN Client Distribution Tool

Tags: desktop-client, vpn, installer

I need to provide clients off-site access to a small-scale network.

Currently, I have an ASUS RT-N16 tool installed, running TomatoVPN firmware.  On this firmware, I can (relatively easily) configure either a PPTP or an OpenVPN Server to provide remote access.

From my research, I think PPTP is just way more insecure than I am comfortable with.  That leaves OpenVPN, except the end-users--the people I am actually trying to grant remote access--are notoriously technically un-savvy.  Unfortunately, OpenVPN through Tomato relies on bi-directional authorization which means setting up OpenVPN configuration and signed certificate on every client.  My end-users (hell, most of my installers) lack the technical know-how to perform this set-up on their machines.

Is there a tool out there, that will let me bundle all the required key files along with the OpenVPN client into a single package, that will properly install on a Windows machine and configure an end-user's OpenVPN so all they need to do is click "Next" and let the .msi figure out the rest?